# Jquery how to change your website background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vs-web-site-project

In my website, I have css like this:

```
body { 
  background: #FFF url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
}
```

So it set my background image, and what I want to do is when user load some page the background image is change, not only for this page he is current on but for all.

How can I do this ?

For now I have script like this:

```
<script>
document.body.style.background="#FFF url('../images/bg2.png') no-repeat center fixed";
</script>
```

So it change my background image but only for that current page, others all loaded with default background image defined in css :(

i didnt mention that the name of image is provided in the page where i want to change that bacground and it is dynamic

USER ACTION EXAMPLE:
here we are going to website like www.example.com and there is some bacground i change page to www.example.com/account i have the same bacground and when i go to www.example.com/change
i want to change my bacground image so when no i go again to www.example.com/account the image is also changed

Comment: That will inject the style as inline, so make sure you change the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML5 `localStorage` to store the style.

Then when load:

```
$("body").css("background",localStorage.style);
```

Comment: can you provide some example ?

Comment: After loading a certain page, execute a script like `localStorage.style = "#FFF url('../images/bg2.png') no-repeat center fixed";`. So when the user loads another page, when `$("body").css("background",localStorage.style);` is executed, it loads the previously stored style.

Comment: Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/N5k6A/
Put the `$("body").css("background-color",localStorage.style);
` on pages you want.

Answer (score 2):

Write your `script` in a file and include that file in all the pages using the `<script>` tag.

Or the other solution is-

Just write the script in all pages! But I don't think you want to do that repetitive work because if someday you plan to change the script, you have to change it on all pages. But in the first solution that I mentioned, you have to change it at only one place.

**Added:**

Based on your comments, what I can think of is-

1- Create a global variable which is persistent across all your pages on your site. Before Every time you load a page, check whether it is true or false. If it is true, use the old background. If it is false use the new background. Keep it true by default and when you open the `www.example.com/change` page, you set it to false.

2- Place the CSS for background in a file. When you load this `www.example.com/change` page, change the contents of this file.

Comment: that cant be, becous i want to change that becground only when user load a specific apge, if not the default have to be displayed and after action the second one always

Comment: @Vardius its hard to understand what you are saying, maybe you are not framing it correctly in English :)

Comment: so like that:
here we are going to website like www.example.com and there is some bacground i change page to www.example.com/account i have the same bacground and when i go to www.example.com/change
i want to change my bacground image so when no i go again to www.example.com/account the image is also changed

Answer (score 0):

```
 simply by : 

$('body').css('background','url(imagefile.png)');
```

Comment: will it change my bacground at all pages? after loading script at one page will another which include css style also have changed bacground ?

Comment: yes it work for all the pages you just have to make your javascript page included in all other pages ! 

like : ex.js is the file which has the above code

and u have index1.html , index2.html and so on ..

just add     <script src="ex.js"></script>     in all the pages

Comment: ok, i know where are we missunderstand i didnt mention that the name of image is provided in the www.example.com/change page and it is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

or this

```
$(this).css("background", "url('../images/r-srchbg_white.png'))
```

or this

```
$(this).parent().css("background", "url('../images/r-srchbg_white.png') no-repeat");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default layout for all pages...like master page......

In that master page body only, you will be loading all your pages html,

If the user loaded that specific page, change the background image of the master page  and change will be affected to the all pages because all pages inherit from master page.